# MySQL Cluster - Cannot assign requested address

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing

I can't start my DBNode of MySql Cluster. Firewall for MGM and DBNode is already turned off.

/usr/local/mysql/bin/ndbd

```
2012-07-20 14:45:20 [ndbd] INFO     -- Angel connected to 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1186'
2012-07-20 14:45:20 [ndbd] INFO     -- Angel allocated nodeid: 2
2012-07-20 14:45:20 [ndbd] ERROR    -- Could not fetch configuration/invalid configuration, error: 'The hostname this node should have according to the configuration does not match a local interface. Attempt to bind 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1' failed with error: 99 'Cannot assign requested address''
```

Comment: perhaps the computer has not been assigned an ip address yet? is this running on startup?

Comment: MGM is started already.

I can actually PING DataNode1 from MGM server and vice versa.

Comment: I am using CLOUD server for the setup. I am also having multiple or or different subnets. Does this effect the setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay got this fixed.

Make a Virtual Local Area Network (VLAN).